# Different SD with simulated stationary AR(1) series

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I need to simulate a number of `AR(1)` series, with a fixed mean (300) and `SD(21)` and `53` data points.

However, when I use the command

`s<-arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.8), n=53,sd=21) + 300`

time and again, if I calculate the SD of the simulated series, it's around `32`, `33` rather than the requested `sd=21`.. First I thought it was because of my small sample size, but even if I put n at `100000`, I still get the wrong `SD`.

Does anyone know what is happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Someone on the talkstats forum answered it for me. SD=21 is the standard deviation of the **error term** in the model, **not the series**. So I have to derive it by using:

y(t) = rho*y(t-1) + e(t)

Var[y(t)] = rho^2 * Var[y(t-1)] + Var[e(t)] ==>

Var[y(t)] = Var[e(t)]/(1-rho^2)

or in other words, in my case the formula is sqrt(21^2/(1-0.8^2))
which is 35

http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/59255-Different-SD-with-simulated-stationary-AR(1)-series?p=169595&posted=1#post169595

Answer (score 0):

The sd in the command is for the residuals. You are computing the standard deviation of the resulting time series.